# Finding the solution to $\frac{d^2 h(y)}{dy^2}-2y\frac{dh(y)}{dy}+(e-1)h(y)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

I have this diff equation:   $\frac{d^2 h(y)}{dy^2}-2y\frac{dh(y)}{dy}+(e-1)h(y)=0$

I am having trouble understanding the method of solution given by the textbook:

[image]

This is only part of the solution but i having trouble understating the step that led to (9.27).

---

- How are we able to change the $s->s+1$ for just one term and not the whole term.
- Why is $s=0$ in that term and not $s=1$
- Is there a general rule for relabelling the dummy summation index that you could list

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Answer (score 1):

The name of summing index is always dummy this means that
$$\sum_{s=0}^{\infty} 2s(2s-1) a_s y^{2s-2}= \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} 2t(2t-1) a_t y^{2t-2}$$
Now let the first term in (9.26) be
$$F=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} 2t(2t-1) a_t ~y^{2t-2}$$
$$F= 0 a_0 y^{-2}+ \sum_{t=1}^{\infty} 2t(2t-1) a_t~ y^{2t-2}$$
Now put $t=s+1 \implies t-1=s $ to get
$$F=\sum_{s+1=1}^{\infty} 2(s+1)(2s+1) a_{s+1}~ y^{2s}=\sum_{s=0}^{\infty} 2(s+1)(2s+1) a_{s+1}~ y^{2s}$$

The main motivation was to have similar power of $y$ as $y^{2s}$in both terms of 9.26. Now replace the first term of 9.26 as above and get 9.27. Yhis is usually done in the series solution of ODEs.